# SQL Server CE vs SqlClient

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce, sqlclient

What is the difference between `SqlServerCe` and `SqlClient` code? Does EF code first require `SqlServerCe`, or is it capable of `SqlClient` also? What provider should I choose if I am operating on a local database?

My `app.config` looks like this:

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory 
            type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
        <parameters>
            <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
        </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
                  type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" 
                  type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" 
                  type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
<DbProviderFactories>
    <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
    <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" 
         invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" 
         description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" 
         type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" 
         invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" 
         description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" 
         type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
  <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
  <add name="SQLite Data Provider" 
       invariant="System.Data.SQLite" 
       description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" 
       type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
</DbProviderFactories>
```

I would like to get rid of `SqlServerCe` or `SqlClient` since I see no reason for both providers in my configuration.

Edit: what provider should I choose if I would focus on an Azure driven DB? (Does local or remote DB require a different provider)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SqlServerCe` is for the single-user, single-machine SQL Server **Compact Edition**, which is officially no longer supported by Microsoft.

`SqlClient` is the provider for the **full, complete** SQL Server as we know it - also the basis for the Azure database offerings.

EF 6 supports both providers for sure.

If you want to remove anything - by all means remove `SqlServerCe` and keep the real, full SQL Server around! But from a technical perspective, those are two *very different* database technologies, and there quite possibly might be situations where you need both